# How to ignore duplicate row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I can ignore duplicate records and get single value with `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`,
but can I ignore completely that rows which contains duplicate value?

this is my `query`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_favourite_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id`
FROM `user_favourite_bookmarks`
LEFT JOIN `user_bookmarks` ON `user_favourite_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id`=`user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id`
AND `user_bookmarks`.`user_id`=14
```

and I am getting single `bookmark_id`, which has duplicate, can I ignore that value also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `distinct`, you can do it using `group by` and `having`

```
SELECT user_favourite_bookmarks.bookmark_id from user_favourite_bookmarks 
LEFT JOIN user_bookmarks ON user_favourite_bookmarks.bookmark_id=user_bookmarks.bookmark_id AND user_bookmarks.user_id=14
group by user_favourite_bookmarks.bookmark_id
having count(*) = 1
```